# como criar sistema de busca usando filtro

Tags: php, html, mysql

Tenho um sistema de busca onde eu busco os usuarios filtrando por: nome, idade e email. Se eu filtrar por nome e idade e email, tudo ocorre bem, mais se eu filtrar somente por idade, por exemplo, nada é retornado mesmo tento no banco dados corretos. Acho que estou fazendo da forma errada, pois uso o operador AND na query, ou seja, quero que as três retornem verdadeiras, mais não é bem isso que quero. Quero filtrar por: idade, ou por idade e email, ou por idade e email e nome.

```
<?php 
$nome = addslashes($_GET['nome']);
$idade = addslashes($_GET['idade']);
$email = addslashes($_GET['email']);
    $sql = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE nome = '$nome' AND idade = '$idade' AND email = '$email' ");

?>
```

Comment: Você tem que montar querys verificando se recebe valores nulos nos parametros.

Comment: Tem que fazer query separada para cada situação.

Answer (score 0):

Não encontrei erros no código, para mim funcionou perfeitamente, o que pode estar ocorrendo é que sua variável que recebe o $_GET da idade não está recebendo valor algum, nesse caso recomendo que execute o código abaixo para verificar se as variáveis estão recebendo valores.

```
<?php 
$nome = addslashes($_GET['nome']);
$idade = addslashes($_GET['idade']);
$email = addslashes($_GET['email']);

//verifica se todos os campos estao recebendo valores
if(!is_null($nome) && !is_null($idade) && !is_null($email)){
    echo "Todos os campos estão enviando valor";
}else{
    echo "Algum campo nao esta correto";
}
?>
```

Outra dica que tenho para você, é usar o PDO dessa forma para pesquisar dados no banco de dados, percebi está utilizando PDO, logo está em busca de maior segurança para seu código.

```
//select de dados de uma forma mais segura
$sql = $pdo->prepare("SELECT nome, idade, email FROM usuarios WHERE nome = :nome AND idade = :idade AND email = :email");
$sql->bindParam(':nome', $nome, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sql->bindParam(':idade', $nome, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sql->bindParam(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sql->execute();
$linha = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
?>
```

De qualquer forma, espero ter ajudado amigo.

Comment: obrigado pelo emprenho na resposta mas o meu problema continua o problema esta que quando pesquiso por um so exemplo por idade logo os os outros estarao vazio certo e justamente ai que esta o erro pois mais como na minha query tem o operador AND para nome e email ele vai retorna nenhum resultado pois estao vindo vazio o que eu quero que quando pesquisa por idade por exemplo as outras sejam excluidas da query se eu pesquisa por idade e email entao a nome seja excluida da query

Comment: Entendi, tente utilizar o operador **OR** ao invés de **AND**.

Answer (score 0):

Aqui tem um exemplo de como montar uma consulta condicional de acordo com os campos enviados:

```
<?php
$where = array();
$nome = "";
$idade = "";
$email = "";
if(isset($_GET['nome'])) {
    if(($_GET['nome'] <> "") {
        $nome = $_GET['nome'];
        $where[] = 'nome LIKE :nome';
    }
}
if(isset($_GET['idade'])) {
    if($_GET['idade'] <> ""){
        $idade = $_GET['idade'];
        $where[] = 'idade LIKE :idade';
    }
}
if(isset($_GET['email'])) {
    if($_GET['email'] <> ""){
        $email = $_GET['email'];
        $where[] = 'email = :email';
    }
}

if(count($where)) {
    $sql = $pdo->prepare("SELECT nome, idade, email FROM usuarios WHERE ".implode(' AND ',$where));

    if($nome <> "") {
        $sql->bindParam(':nome', $nome, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    }   

    if($idade <> ""){
        $sql->bindParam(':idade', $idade, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    }   

    if($email <> ""){
        $sql->bindParam(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    }

    $sql->execute();

}
?>
```

Comment: Você inicia uma variável com string vazia e depois só atualiza o valor dela se ela não for uma string vazia. Basicamente o valor nunca será atualizado, seu *array* `$where` sempre será um *array* vazio, independente da entrada e, assim, o último `if` nunca será executado. Em outras palavras, no final das contas o código faz nada. Acredito que você tenha se equivocado nos operadores que utilizou, poderia rever a resposta?

Comment: Tem razão, me equivoquei na hora de inserir a resposta, já fiz a correção. Obrigado por avisar.

Answer (score -1):

Muda sua query para isso

```
$sql = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE nome LIKE '$nome' OR idade = '$idade' OR email LIKE '$email' ");
```